# Joomla custom fields plugin wont save inputted data when attempting to only show it on certain categories within the article manager

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

I am currently putting together a simple plugin for Joomla to show custom fields within the article editor. Everything works perfectly until I try and configure it to only show on certain categories. Once I tell the custom fields to only show on a certain category the fields show fine buy they wont save at all.

Here's my function as it stands:

```
function onContentPrepareForm($form, $data) {
    $app = JFactory::getApplication();
    $option = $app->input->get('option');
    switch($option) {
        case 'com_content':
            if ($app->isAdmin()) {
                JForm::addFormPath(__DIR__ . '/forms');
                if ( $data->catid == '9' ) {
                    $form->loadFile('this', false);
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    return true;
}
```

So adding 'if ( $data->catid == '9' )' does the job and I only see my fields on catid 9 but when I add that clause it no longer saves.

Here's what my form xml looks like:

```
<form>
<fields name="params">
    <fieldset name="this">

        <field name="note01" type="note" label="this" />

        <field name="row_1_toggle" type="radio" class="btn-group btn-group-yesno"
                default="no"
                label="Show Row 1"
            >
                <option value="yes">Yes</option>
                <option value="no">No</option>
        </field>

    </fieldset>
</fields>
```

Comment: have you found a solution to this by any chance? getting the exact same behaviour